# Is there any way to search good questions in C on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am a novice user here, but Stack Overflow really helps me to learn some deep concepts in C programming. I am just really enjoying solving many questions in C here.

But there are a lot of questions related to every tag like C, string, struct, union, etc.

Is there a possibility to filter or search some really asked good questions or some nice concepts?

---

Example: When I clicked the Struct tag - it shows some 9000 questions, but some of them (actually maximum) are very nice constructive and concept building.

So, here comes my question: How do I know those questions or filter them so that I can practice much of coding questions? Or, do I have to search every page and every single question?

Comment: Sort by votes on question page.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Yeah, I solved many top voted questions by doing that only .

Comment: If you don't know, there is the documentation too : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/topics

Comment: Sorting by "linked" seems like a good place to start, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?filter=all&sort=linked Usually links indicate that someone else asked a related question and linked back to this one, so it's an issue that comes up frequently.

Comment: You can also chain the tags to find specific area for example : `[c] [byte]` would show byte-related `C` questions and that can be sorted by "votes" too.

Comment: You can filter the search so that it only shows questions with a certain amount of votes. For example, searching for `[c] votes:10 is:question` only shows you questions tagged [c] with 10 votes or more.

Comment: @Walfrat I'd be wary of documentation, it's slowly becoming the W3Schools of SO. It's sort of like the love child of wikipedia (questionably written, by anybody with a keyboard) and archive.org (just a copy of content that already exists elsewhere), with the dubious precision of W3Schools.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726663/switch-case-wont-compile-after-commenting-out-an-unused-line

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments you can sort by votes and also you can visit the profile page of top users in some particular tag in your case it is [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Find them here

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/topusers

Answer (score 1):

You can click the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag then click the votes tag and sort by upvotes. This will mostly give you "what is this curious syntax" questions though, it isn't very good reading.

A better place to search is the [frequent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=frequent&pageSize=50). This gives you a list of good questions that are frequently linked or used as "canonical duplicates". There's all manner of questions there, from beginner to advanced level.

Comment: Thanks !!! That helps very much .